# Websockets and telnet connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, websocket

Does anyone know if it is possible to use HTML-WebSockets to listen to a telnet stream?

Description: I have a DSL-Phone-Router (Fritzbox) which has a "Callmonitor"-function. This sends for every incoming/outgoing call a telnet line with specific info.

I can see this stream, when I run...

```
telnet fritz.box 1012
```

on my Windows-CMD or MAC-Terminal.

My Question: Is it possible that HTML5-Websockets can listen to this stream? Or can HTML5-Websockets only listen to a Websockets-Server like node.js etc...?

Comment: Yeah, websockets itself even has its own protocol (ws:) and needs to be connected to a server that understands it.  However, you might be able to get the server to monitor the telnet, and send the stream over a websockets connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [websockify project](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) was created for exactly this sort of thing. It is a python program that bridges between the WebSocket clients and raw TCP servers. You will need somewhere to run websockify, but the websockify requirements are fairly minimal. Also, you will need to implement the client side (HTML/Javascript) to display the stream, but websockify includes a wstelnet.html example that you should be able to modify or use directly for that purpose. **Disclaimer**: I created websockify.